# What does mean --[[ in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I'm googling for a long time but there are no explanation of my problem. When I input in NodeJS interpreter `--[[` then it does not allow me do something else. Is it a bug or it's a feature which I can use? How? Could someone explain me this? Thanks for advance.

Comment: Why were you inputting that to start with?

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter is waiting for you to close the two arrays you opened with `[[` and will keep accepting input until you close both with `]]`, at which point it will correctly crash because you cannot subtract (`--`) from an array.